# How to render base-64 string in <img> tag without knowing extension

Tags: image, url, base64

We have a small feature on our site which allows users to upload a profile picture.  This picture will then be stored in our Postgres database as a base-64 encoded string.  My question concerns the data scheme used in an `<img>` URL to render a base-64 encoded string, e.g.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgo ...">
                     ^^^   but what if we don't know the extension?
```

We plan on simply storing a base-64 blob and nothing else.  But in this case, how could we know what extension was used in the original file?  I have briefly tested Chrome and IE 10, and they appear to be happy opening a PNG file with any image extension whatsoever, e.g. even `data:image/zzz` seemed to work.  But I have read elsewhere that for certain image formats, e.g. TIFF, the correct extension must be given.

If having the correct extension be mandatory to render a base-64 string in an `<img>` tag, then does this mean that we would need to send the file extension to the UI in addition to the base-64 string itself?

Answer (score 1):

I will offer this as a partial answer to my own question.  As it turns out, most base 64 libraries and tools actually generate the `data:image/ext` portion of the encoded string automatically, along with the actual `base64` data.  Hence, at least for our production setup, knowing the extension was a moot point because the Apache library we were using took care of this automatically.